# Android Continuously play and stop audio files

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am building an Android application and I want to play multiple audio files back to back. I have a lot of audio files so I don't want to load them at once but as they are needed. I also need a way to stop the continuous playback. So as input I have a File[] array of audio files and I need a way to start continuously playing and stop. I saw MediaPlayer as a way to play the audio files but I wasn't sure how to continuously play them and stop on demand.

Answer (score 0):

The [Media Playback API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) contains everything you need to know. You can also check the RandomMusicPlayer included in the Android SDK samples.